# Android app preflight http OPTION request getting failed with net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, preflight, http-options-method

I have one android application, before each and every user actions preflight http options request is getting fired from application, recently we have been getting complaints from number of users that application is not working properly and it keeps loading and loading, to troubleshoot issue, we got debug application, upon checking we found that users who are facing issues, on their device, when user is initiating any action like login, preflight request is getting failed with error net::ERR_TIMED_OUT, when request is getting failed with this we are not getting request on our server/firewall.

suppose preflight request is getting fired on domain https://example.com, when user is not able to access application, at the same time when we open browser on users device and access domain https://example.com (GET method), domain is accessible from device, then why preflight  request is getting failed with net::ERR_TIMED_OUT ?

if my app has 100 users then 20 out of 100 users are facing this issue, for 80 users application is working as expected, and for 20 users preflight request is getting failed, so they are not able to access application.

[image]